# Memory leak even if I release retained objects in onDestroy?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-context, android-memory

I know that this is a bad idea to pass context/activity to another object that may live longer then activity and store it, but in my app I really need this. Here is a pseudocode that I'm using

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements ActivityDelegate {
  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   MySingleton.getShared().setDelegate(this);

  }

  void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   MySingleton.getShared().setDelegate(null);

  }

}
class MySingleton{
  private static MySingleton shared;
  private ActivityDelegate delegate = null;

  public static MySingleton getShared() {
   if (shared == null)
     shared = new MySingleton();
   return shared;
  }

  void setDelegate(ActivityDelegate delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }
 
}
```

As you can see I always set `delegate` to `null` in `onDestroy`, this is why memory leak should not occur. But as far as I know there are some cases when `onDestroy` is not called. I guess this only happens when the entire app process is purged and the memory get released anyway. So, my question is - is this safe to pass context/activity to another object and then unset it in `onDestroy` call or it can still cause leaks in some cases ? 
Thanks

Comment: The case where `onDestroy` is not called is when your whole app is getting exited, so in that case it doesn't matter if you leak anything. But if you're having to pass the Activity around to singletons, I suspect the design of the app is not well-organized. Note that it is safe to store the Application Context in singletons without cleaning up its references.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah, I know that this is not the best design, but this was the easiest way to achieve the goal in the current setup. So, basically as far as I understood what I'm doing is safe, right ?

Comment: Your code above is safe, but error prone. Easy now could mean very difficult later when you're hunting down bugs.